# What if I want to print the line number after each touched line in Java?

Tags: java, code-coverage

Since the Java program contains several conditional statements, I want to track which line numbers each execution has touched in different trials. What could I do?

Say, if I am going through a conditional statement "if(x==1) x++", "if(x==1)" is in line 6 and x++ is in line 7. If I insert Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber() in the end of this if statement, it could only print "line 7", but actually both line 6 and 7 are touched. How could I print both line numbers?

Comment: Use a code-coverage tool?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools

Comment: Any method to do the implementation by self? Since the trial data need to go through further analysis...

Comment: Most of the tools listed on wikipedia are Open Source. If none of them can do what you need you can add what you need as a new feature to one of them.

Comment: JaCoCo seems promising - it can write its output to file or to a socket for further analysis.